# how to read a string and integer separately from a file in python

Tags: python, string, integer

I having trouble reading a file. I have a small text file, like one underneath. My program is supposed to read the first string and store the rest of the integers and sort them in increasing order. I have to write my program in python, but I haven't able to figure out. How to separate my string and integers. Then in the end i have output the result with the name and sorted in integers.

## !/usr/bin/env/python

```
import sys
import os


def main():
   h = []
   
  infile = open(sys.argv[1], "rb")
   
  str = infile.readline()
   
  for line in infile:
            
     for nbr in line.split():
                    
        h.append(nbr)
    

 infile.close()

main()
```

Comment: Post your code attempt too.

Comment: Can you please show what you've tried? Can you provide an [mcve]? What is your expect output? What is your actually output? Can you show us rather than tell us? This question as is, is currently to broad.

Comment: Is this the entire file, or just part of it?

Comment: Yes, I can post my code, I was able to separate string and integers. Now have to sort the integers in priority queue order. here is my code

Comment: #!/usr/bin/env/python

import sys
import os

def heapsort(iterable):
        file = []
        for value in iterable:
                heappush(h,value)
        return[heappop(h) for i in range(len(file))]
def main():
        h = []
        infile = open(sys.argv[1], "rb")
        str = infile.readline()
        for line in infile:
                for nbr in line.split():
                        h.append(nbr)
        print str
        print h
        infile.close()
main()

Comment: Please post your code in the question itself, along with your desired output from this file.

Comment: i need to sort using heap queue algorithm, but I dont how to do it

Comment: I posted my code. desired output can be any file with first string and next integers

Answer (score 0):

You can use regex and `heapq`:

```
import re
import heapq

f = [i.strip('\n') for i in open('filename.txt')]
new_f = [re.findall("(?<=\d{1,}\.\s)[a-zA-Z0-9]+", i) for i in f]
def heapqueue_sort(numbers):
    l = []
    heapq.heapify(l)
    for i in numbers:
        heapq.heappush(l, i)
    return [heapq.heappop(l) for i in range(len(l))]
final_data = [new_f[0]].extend(heapqueue_sort(map(int, new_f[1:]))]
print(final_data)
```

Comment: where are you sending values into number?can you explain please

Comment: @Gloria_2015 I am not sure what you mean. Are you referring to the function call?

Comment: yes, can you explain how map of int and new_f works in this method

Comment: @Gloria_2015 map takes a specific function, in this case the integer function, and applies it to every element in the list. `new_f` searches for the integer values after the decimal in your file.